# How to minimize reactive form validation script in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I tried to reduce script in reactive form validation but not working. Anyone can find the mistake from my code.

**Form Angular Builder Code**

```
    public obj=["firstName","lastName",'password','confirmPassword'];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          for(var i=0;i<=this.obj.length;i++){ 
           this.obj[i]: ['', Validators.required]
          } 
     email: new FormControl('',{Validators:[Validators.required],updateOn:'blur'})
        } );
    }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-reactive-form-validation-rzsfa9?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: are you sure about this condtion? `i<=this.obj.length` it must be `i< this.obj.length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the declaration and ngOnInit() function to below code

```
registerForm;
submitted = false;
obj=["firstName","lastName",'email','password','confirmPassword'];
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.registerForm = new FormGroup({});
  for(var i=0;i<=this.obj.length;i++){
    if(this.obj[i] == "email"){
      this.registerForm.addControl(this.obj[i], new FormControl('',[ Validators.required,Validators.email]))
    }
    else
    {
      this.registerForm.addControl(this.obj[i], new FormControl('', Validators.required))
    }

  };

}
```

Here is the link to the updated code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-reactive-form-validation-dmq3bq

Comment: I have edited my code.If i have more different control like email..how can i control it?

Comment: If you have different type of control, then write if condition to check `if this.obj[i] == "email" or this.obj[i] == 'password'` and write separate validator for them

Comment: @NilaVaani are you sure `this.registerForm = new FormGroup();` line is working?

Comment: Just change it to this.registerForm = new FormGroup({});

Comment: Some form like this: 'firstName' : ['', Validators.required] ..firstName inside single quatation..so in this condition your script will be work????

Comment: Yes it is working. Please change the import to  `import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators,FormControl } from '@angular/forms';`

Comment: This is not working: obj=["firstName","lastName",'email','password','confirmPassword']; 
    for(var i=0;i<=this.obj.length;i++){
    this.registerForm.controls[obj[i]].reset();
    }

Comment: If you want to reset, then why you are reseting individual controls. Simply use `this.registerForm.reset()`

Comment: Particular fields only i want to reset: obj=['email','password','confirmPassword']; for(var i=0;i<=this.obj.length;i++){ this.registerForm.controls[obj[i]].reset(); }

Comment: this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({});  line is not working

Answer (score 1):

```
  registerForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  obj = ["firstName", "lastName", "email", "password", "confirmPassword"];

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= this.obj.length; i++) {
      this.registerForm.addControl(
        this.obj[i],
        new FormControl("", Validators.required)
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have one doubt in nodejs+angular6, Can i ask you?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
arr = [];tmp={}
validationFun(){
  for(var i=0;i<this.obj.length;i++){
    this.tmp[this.obj[i]] = ['', Validators.required];
    this.arr.push(this.tmp)
  }
  return this.arr[0];
}
```

And then call validationFun()

```
 this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      this.validationFun()
    );
```

Comment: How to reset particular fields only i want to reset: obj=['email','password','confirmPassword']; for(var i=0;i<=this.obj.length;i++){ this.registerForm.controls[obj[i]].reset(); }

Comment: this.registerForm.get('email').reset()

Comment: Aarray fields??

Comment: Where is Array its an obj

Comment: Can you answer this? obj=['email','password','confirmPassword']; for(var i=0;i<=this.obj.length;i++){ this.registerForm.controls[obj[i]].reset(); }    How can i reset particular fields ?

Comment: Stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-reactive-form-validation-e5gbvf?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: check resetfn()